# child routes angular 2 FINAL RELEASE Cannot find primary outlet to load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i'm trying to setup my routing section but i'm having the error: **Cannot find primary outlet to load 'component** what i want is something like this:

```
appComponent
     \
      \
      child1
        \
         \
          child 2
```

**What i currently have:**

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/index',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'index',
            component: moduleTermsComponent,
            data: { name: 'index' }
        },
        {
            path: 'module/:name',
            component: moduleComp,
            data: { name: 'module' },
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':info', component: childComp,
                        children: [
                        { path: ':id', component: subchildComp },
                    ]            
                }
        ]
}
    ];
```

Basically i need to generate a router tree in order me be able to see what's the parent route of a route and with that create a breadcrumb

i has been searching a lot in google but everytthing is about older versions of angular 2, so i wonder if somebody can explain what's happening and some thoughts about posibles solutions to this, or better ideas to achieve the main goal that is create the breadcrumb for the current route

thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: @peeskillet yes i do

Comment: I think maybe the child components that have their own children, might also need their own router-outlet. Not sure. But do you also have this?

Comment: For how your routes are set up, you will need more than one `<router-outlet>`. You'll need one in the AppComponent, moduleComp, and childComp or else there won't be a place to display the components' children.

Comment: I was having a similar issue myself. Which routes work for you and which routes give the "Cannot find primary outlet" error?